# For ThreeJS, 'm looking for a Helper class or utility that works like AxisHelper

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In working with Three.js and I’ve run across several useful Helper classes that really make displaying and or modifying the scene much easier.  There is one tool out there that I can’t seem to find again.  It is kind of like the AxisHelper however it has a plane between the axis when you mouse over that area allowing the user to move the object along the xy, xz, or yz plane depending on what you pick.  I’ve drawn an example of what it adds to the object in order to help the user move the object along the plane.  If anyone knows of this tool or maybe an example of something that uses a utility like this, it would be great if you could point it out to me.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are looking for `TransformControls`. There is a three.js example of its use [here](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html).

`TransformControls` is not part of the library -- it is part of the examples. You must include it explicitly in your project.

three.js r.80

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking ALL OVER for this!